# R - How to extract an element from a single column data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and need to access the 1st row in the 1st column (Negative=16)

```
[[1]]
              data
Negative        16
Neutral         36
Positive        28
Very Negative    7
Very Positive   19

List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ data: int [1:5] 16 36 28 7 19
```

I have tried the following:

```
x(1,1)
# Error in x(1, 1) : could not find function "x"

x[1,1]
# Error in x[1, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

x['Negative',1]
# Error in x["Negative", 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

x['Negative']
# $<NA>
# NULL
```

Comment: It looks like you have a list of length 1 that contains your data.frame. You may want to strip off the outer list if this the only dataset you'll be working with: `x <-unlist(x, recursive=FALSE)` or `x <- x[[1]]`. With the initial structure, you could use the esoteric method of recursive indexing like this: `x[[rep(1L, 3L)]]`, which is equivalent to `x[[c(1, 1, 1)]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read only the first column from a data frame like this:

```
x <- df[1,, drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: I think `df[1,, drop = F]` will produce the result that @Asif is asking.

Comment: yeah I think so. I was reading again and he wants the 1st row and column

Comment: @GabrielMesquita  guys thank you all for your assistance. This really helped me in understanding the difference.

Comment: No problem @AsifHameed, if it helped remember to mark as correct answer :)